# How to use the burn:/// location?

Tags: pantheon-files

This might be rather stupid, but I did not easily find an answer to this. When putting an empty CD into the drive, a new device with the location `burn:///` is shown. However, there is no clue how to use it. I tried copying files into the empty directory, but this does not work. Is this supposed to work? What is the suggested method on Elementary OS to burn CDs?

Comment: I was wondering the same. I guess Files it's not feature complete and the idea is to add burn capabilities like Gnome's Nautilus

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the `burn:///` location but based on experience, I can recommend the [K3b](http://www.k3b.org/) burner. It's available in the Software Center.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the reply. I installed a burning application (brasero, did not really care which one), but I am wondering what the burn:/// is supposed to be good for. It looks like it is supposed to be used for burning CDs, but it is unclear how to me how to actually use it...

Comment: Brasero fits better with elementary, because it's meant for GNOME based systems. K3b on the other hand is meant for KDE desktops. The reason why I recommended K3b is that I have heard that several have had problems with Brasero.